# Need help in a batch script: use 1 or 2 arrays OR parse a file with a tuple name number

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd, sql-loader

I want to run a sqlldr command customized with some parameters, more precisely a name and a associated number. For now I only have an iteration through names but I want to associate each of it with a number.

```
@echo off
set ORACLE_PWD=orcl
set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,
setlocal
echo "Run number " %1
For %%X in (region nation supplier customer part partsupp orders lineitem) do (
sqlldr userid='sys/%ORACLE_PWD% as sysdba' log=%%X%1.log control=%%X.ctl direct=true rows=<associated_number> multithreading=true
)
```

I have 2 options: do it with another array of numbers (which may the hardest thing) or parse a text file like:

```
region 25 (or region DELIMITER 25)  
nation 100
supplier 5000
```

and so on

and then get those values to vars and use them in the sqlldr command to customize my log name and the number of rows.

I understand that arrays in batch script are a nightmare and I'm trying but I can't get it right. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save this:

```
region 25
nation 100
supplier 5000
```

in a file named, for example, `params.txt`, then this script will read the file and substitute the values accordingly:

```
@echo off
set ORACLE_PWD=orcl
set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=.,
setlocal
echo "Run number " %1
For /F "tokens=1,2" %%X in (params.txt) do (
sqlldr userid='sys/%ORACLE_PWD% as sysdba' log=%%X%1.log control=%%X.ctl direct=true rows=%%Y multithreading=true
)
```